# How to make a game object draw lines to another similar game objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As I said, these game objects have some characteristics, each of they have an area that they keep raycasing a circle (RaycastSphereAll) and they catch all similar game objects (I don't know if this is the best aproach).

So how I connect these game objects like shown in this image below based on near game objects?

I don't know how to do this code and I don't know how to make in this "object oriented" way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) API reference on Unity's website, it sounds like what you're looking for. Then if you give these objects that you want to draw lines between certain tags, you could search your scene for objects with those same tags, create a static list, and draw lines to each one from each one.

Comment: But drawing lines from each one to each one will create repeated lines.

Comment: @ST2015 True. Could also make just one script outside of the objects that draws all the lines by iterating through a list.